# How To Efficiently Navigate Websites via PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have been working with PhantomJS recently, but have found that overall usage of it is very inefficient. By this I mean requests either succeed or time out based on an interval value, and early completion would result in wasted time. I am basing my script off of [this example here](https://peteris.rocks/blog/configuring-websites-with-phantomjs/). As the speed of my internet varies, it makes lines like this:

```
setInterval(executeRequestsStepByStep, 50)
```

VERY iffy. I was wondering if there are any solutions to something like this that would eliminate a set value such as this. I have been thinking `steps[]` from the example could be run through based on whether or not the page had finished loading, but am not sure how to implement this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read that script thoroughly, there is a flag to block execution while a page is loading. I agree, 50ms is too small an interval, 500ms sounds a bit more reliable to me.

Comment: I agree, it would be. But it would also be more likely to waste time and resources. Which is what we all obviously try to avoid

Comment: I would consider selenium if I were you. It's got lots of methods for waiting for specific elements to load, etc.